# pandas.DataFrame.applymap returns a pandas Series if "python -O" is used

Tags: python, pandas

I am using python to read some data from a file and store them in a pandas data frame. The file with the data is "test.prn" and contains:

```
    A  B
0 0.0  2
1 1.0  3
```

Below, I attached my small code to illustrate what happens. When executing the code, "python my_prog.py", everything works as expected and read_csv returns a pandas frame. However, if I execute as "python -O my_prog.py", I get a pandas series. Does anybody know why there is this unwanted change? I need that the return of read_csv be a pandas frame, regardless of the python arguments.

my_prog.py:

```
import pandas as pd
pdf1 = pd.DataFrame()
pdf1 = pd.read_csv('test.prn', sep='\s+', header=0, index_col=0)
pdf2 = pdf1.applymap(lambda x: x*x)
print type(pdf1)
print type(pdf2)
```

Executing as "python my_prog.py" gives:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Executing as "python -O my_prog.py" gives:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but simply changing the way of passing the file does not solve the problem. I still have a pandas series when executing with python -O

Comment: what if you print  `pdf1`  like `print(pdf1)`, does it runs properly!

Comment: `pdf1 = pd.DataFrame("something_here")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this with Python 2.7.13 and Pandas 0.19.2. I get

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

with and without the `-O` switch.

In your case, it may be a bug in Pandas. If you use an older Pandas version try updating to a more recent one (at least to 0.19.2).

Comment: Dear Sergiy, thanks for taking the time to try. Apparently, I was using pandas 0.16.0. With version 0.22.0 (and python 2.7.9) the problem disappears, as you suggested. I'll mark your answer as the solution. Best, Fabio.

Comment: I upvoted it, but it seems that new members (less than 15 points) cannot really change the status of the answer.